# Filtering a Twitter API array based on specific parameters. Getting the sum and displaying the results

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

I'm using the [140 dev Twitter Framework](http://140dev.com/free-twitter-api-source-code-library/) to pull an array of 100 tweets and filter the results to display only tweets from the last 60 minutes. I also want this as a total number of tweets in the last 60 minutes. NB: This is code from 140 dev that I am adapting to achieve this.

```
<?php 

// The search terms are passed in the q parameter
// search_server.php?q=[search terms]
if (!empty($_GET['q'])) {

    // Remove any hack attempts from input data
    $search_terms = htmlspecialchars($_GET['q']);

    // Get the application OAuth tokens
    require 'app_tokens.php';

    // Create an OAuth connection
    require 'tmhOAuth.php';
    $connection = new tmhOAuth(array(
      'consumer_key'    => $consumer_key,
      'consumer_secret' => $consumer_secret,
      'user_token'      => $user_token,
      'user_secret'     => $user_secret
    ));

    // Request the most recent 100 matching tweets
    $http_code = $connection->request('GET',$connection->url('1.1/search/tweets'), 
                array('q' => $search_terms,
                'count' => 100,
                'lang' => 'en',
                'type' => 'recent'));

    // Search was successful
    if ($http_code == 200) {

        // Extract the tweets from the API response
        $response = json_decode($connection->response['response'],true);
        $tweet_data = $response['statuses']; 


        // Load the template for tweet display
        $tweet_template= file_get_contents('tweet_template.html');

        // Load the library of tweet display functions
        require 'display_lib.php';      

        // Create a stream of formatted tweets as HTML
        $tweet_stream = '';

        $sumArray = array();

        foreach($tweet_data as $key=>$tweet) {  

            $hourcount = $tweet['created_at'];

            $deltatime2 = time() - strtotime($hourcount);

            if ($deltatime2 < (60 * 60)) {
                $deltasum = floor($deltatime2 / 60);
            } 

            // Ignore any retweets
            if (isset($tweet['retweeted_status'])) {
                continue;
            }

            if ($deltasum < 60) {

                $i++;
                // Get a fresh copy of the tweet template
                $tweet_html = $tweet_template;

                // Insert this tweet into the html
                $tweet_html = str_replace('[screen_name]',
                    $tweet['user']['screen_name'],$tweet_html);
                $tweet_html = str_replace('[name]',
                    $tweet['user']['name'],$tweet_html);        
                $tweet_html = str_replace('[profile_image_url]',
                    $tweet['user']['profile_image_url'],$tweet_html);
                $tweet_html = str_replace('[tweet_id]',
                    $tweet['id'],$tweet_html);
                $tweet_html = str_replace('[tweet_text]',
                    linkify($tweet['text']),$tweet_html);
                $tweet_html = str_replace('[created_at]',
                    twitter_time($tweet['created_at']),$tweet_html);
                $tweet_html = str_replace('[retweet_count]',
                    $tweet['retweet_count'],$tweet_html);   
                // Get time value
                $tweet_html = str_replace('[minute_count]', 
                    time_value($tweet['created_at']),$tweet_html);
                // Add the HTML for this tweet to the stream
                $tweet_stream .= $tweet_html;

            } 

        }

        // Pass the tweets HTML back to the Ajax request
        print $tweet_stream;

    // Handle errors from API request
    } else {
        if ($http_code == 429) {
            print 'Error: Twitter API rate limit reached';
        } else {
            print 'Error: Twitter was not able to process that search';
        }
    }

} else {
    print 'No search terms found';
}   

?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your code I read the followng:

```
    $http_code = $connection->request('GET',$connection->url('1.1/search/tweets'), 
            array('q' => $search_terms,
            'count' => 100,
            'lang' => 'en',
            'type' => 'recent'));
```

this implies that you set it alrady to "recent" and the count is 100. It will automatically get the most recent 100 tweets from a given search I'd say.
Isn't the time limit redundant?